# JSONObjectWithData is being skipped by Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The following code is supposed to load "groups" into a table view, however, the table view is blank:

```
do {
    if let jsonDataArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSArray {
        for imageDataDict in jsonDataArray {
            let group = Group(
                id: imageDataDict.valueForKey("id") as! Int,
                name: imageDataDict.valueForKey("name") as! String,
                author: imageDataDict.valueForKey("author") as! Int
            )
            self.dataArray.append(group)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    print("lol")
} catch {
    // report error
    displayAlertMessage("Error", alertDescription: "Oh man, there was an error!")
}
```

I tried setting a breakpoint at `if let jsonDataArray...` and the Xcode stopped at the line. However, when I stepped forward, it directly skipped to `print("lol")`. I am confused why this is happening. Is it because `jsonDataArray` is returning nil?

---

**EDIT: Here is the full function**

```
func loadSelfieData () {
    // Create HTTP request and set request Body
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let user_id = defaults.integerForKey("user_id")
    let httpRequest = httpHelper.buildRequest("groups?user_id=\(user_id)", method: "GET",
        authType: HTTPRequestAuthType.HTTPTokenAuth)

    httpHelper.sendRequest(httpRequest, completion: {(data:NSData!, error:NSError!, description:NSMutableString!) in
        if error != nil {
            let errorMessage = self.httpHelper.getErrorMessage(error)
            displayAlertMessage("Error", alertDescription: errorMessage as String)

            return
        }

        var _ :NSError?

        do {
            if let jsonDataArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSArray {
                for imageDataDict in jsonDataArray {
                    let group = Group(
                        id: imageDataDict.valueForKey("id") as! Int,
                        name: imageDataDict.valueForKey("name") as! String,
                        author: imageDataDict.valueForKey("author") as! Int
                    )
                    self.dataArray.append(group)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            print("lol")
        } catch {
            displayAlertMessage("Error", alertDescription: "there was an error")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: can you provide some additional code

Comment: Is it actually printing out in the terminal, despite missing it when you step through? Occassionally weird stuff like that happens to me when stepping through Swift.

Comment: Only "lol" gets printed in the console. I can see that happening as I step through.

Comment: check if you are getting non nil data in "data"

Comment: data seems to be `NSData` and 41 bytes, so it isn't nil. Furthermore, printing it in the console prints it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a breakpoint at the call to a function which executes a closure and so if you just try to step through from there it will appear as if the inside is not being executed when in fact, it is. Set a breakpoint at a line inside the execution of the closure, such as at the id line, where you'll then be able to see the status of all your data, if there is any.

Comment: I set multiple breakpoints inside a function, but they aren't executing.